# How to break apart an Integer in VHDL?

Tags: integer, vhdl

I need to break apart an integer result of a calculation in order to display its digits on a 7-segment but ISE won't 'accept' anything I try! Maybe convert it to integer_vector? How?

Comment: can you post an example of what you're trying to do? to clarify...

Comment: Can you post any code that didn't work along with the error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to display the number in base 10 on your seven-segment displays, in which case this is actually a relatively complex task. It involves converting your integer, which is stored in binary in hardware, into [binary-coded decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). An 8-bit binary to BCD converter in VHDL can be found [here](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.no/2010/04/8-bit-binary-to-bcd-converter-double.html). Note that it's not straight forward to expand this algorithm to more bits/digits if you need that.

Also note that it would be a lot simpler to display the number in hexadecimal, if that is acceptable.

Comment: This was the solution! It is called 'the Double-Dabble algorithm' and it works fine. Thanks a lot!